# Loading items in ListActivity blocks app

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask, listactivity, progressdialog

Well, I'm making an app in which I'm using a ListActivity to display views that have images that I download from the Internet as well as TextViews and rating bars.
I've added an AsyncTask to manage this and have my setListAdapter in the onPostExecute() part; however, I also wanted a progressbar (or progressdialog )to be shown while the setting was done.

The bar does appear for a while in my emulator, but not when I try my app on a device, and even in the emulator, the bar freezes when the setListAdapter is working but...it's just that I haven't figured out how to add the publishProgress on my ArrayAdapter since it's another class.
Ah yes, I set the layout for the ListActivity and that's where I put the progressBar, but the device I guess makes the doInBackground part quite fast so that layout doesn't even show.

This is what I've got so far:

```
    @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

            extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            platinumCinema = false;
            setContentView(R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

                Log.i(TAG,"Control B");  
                MoviesAsyncTask movieTask = new MoviesAsyncTask();
                movieTask.execute();
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title_billboard);
    }

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);          
        mProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i(TAG, "PreExecute");
         }

     @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if(result.equals("ok"))
                    Log.i(TAG,"Ended succesfully");
                //ProgressDialog mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(BillboardMovieList.this, "","Loading. Please wait...", true);

                publishProgress(75);

             if(searchMethod.equals("byCinema")){
                 setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapterSchemaCinemas(BillboardMovieList.this, listMovies,listPosters, listRating, listTimes));
             }else
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not call `publishProgress()` from `onPostExecute()`. For starters, the progress will not change until after `onPostExecute()` completes, anyway, since `onProgressUpdate()` needs to be called on the main application thread, which is in the middle of running your `onPostExecute()` logic.

If you still feel things are running too slowly, I would recommend that you perhaps use Traceview or simple logging statements to identify exactly where the problem is.

Comment: So far the problem is while setting the listAdapter, since generating this is the task is (if I'm not mistaken) blocking the UI thread in order to generate the list itself. This has to be done in the onPostExecute, right? 'Cause doInBackground cannot handle this, or can it?

Comment: @Paulina D.: You can create the adapter in `doInBackground()`, but you cannot call `setListAdapter()` until `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: How can I only create the adapter then? In the ListView documentation I see no onCreateAdapter or something similar =(

Comment: @Paulina D.: AFAICT, you already are creating the adapter. I see `new ArrayAdapterSchemaCinemas` right in your code. Given the name of the class and that it is being passed to `setListAdapter()`, I am guessing that it is an adapter.

Comment: Mm...well, actually I just moved a piece of code where I was retrieving images from the web (which I have coded into the ArrayAdapterSchema getView) and this was making it all super slow. So lesson learned, anything 'heavy' should definitely go into the doInBackground part.